# Can I use the Caestus with a shield on?

Tags: dark-souls

So, the Cestus has a special ability that, if you consume 3 Stamina, you can use it to attack, even when it is a "backup slot" of your weaponry.

Additionally, there is a rule saying that a player may make as many attacks as they have weapons in their hands.

So, if I have a primary weapon (the Longsword, for example), and a shield, and then place the Cestus in a backup slot (on the shield hand, for example) can I attack with the Cestus *as well as* the sword each turn, or does this just allow me to attack with the Cestus *instead* of the sword?

Answer (score 1):

### **Yes**, you can attack with both your sword and cestus.

The wording in the rule book (pg. 22) is as follows:

> During an activation, a character can make up to one attack
>   with each weapon they are holding in their hand slots.

The special ability of the cestus explicitly states you can use it to attack even when it is in your 'backup slot'. There is no qualifier regarding how many weapons are equipped in your hands. This special ability on the card overrides the general rule on attacks (hence the reason it's a special ability)

This means you could have a 'two-handed' weapon equipped and your cestus in your backup slot, or two single handed items and your cestus in your backup slot.